# Why/when does bash remove trailing newline

Tags: bash, shell, unix

When or how does bash remove the trailing newline in the following examples?

```
echo -n "$(echo foo)" | wc -c # why is this 3 not 4

a="$(echo foo | tail -c 1)" # why is $a empty and not "\n"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/bash/bash.1.en.html#Command_Substitution

> Bash performs the expansion by executing command in a subshell environment and replacing the command substitution with the standard output of the command, with any trailing newlines deleted.

This behaviour is also specified by POSIX: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03

Answer (score 0):

1. echo by default adds a new line character to the string.

e.g., echo 'foo' gives foo and a new line character added at the end. This is the reason why shell prompt(may be $) comes in a new line.

```
$echo 'foo'
foo
$
```

If it is piped with wc -c, it will give 4 as a result because trailing new line character is also counted

```
$echo 'foo' | wc -c
4
$
```

If -n option  is used with echo, default trailing new line character is suppressed and shell prompt appears in the same line.
e.g.,

```
$echo -n 'foo'
foo$
```

Now if number of characters are counted through wc -c, it gives 3 as no trailing new line character is present.

```
$echo -n 'foo' | wc -c
3
```

For the same reason,
`echo -n "$(echo foo)" | wc -c` comes as 3 instead of 4, because -n suppresses the new line character that would have been appeared if -n was not used.
If -n will be removed, you will get 4 as answer.

2. `a="$(echo foo | tail -c 1)"`
   As I can see, `echo $a` gives an empty blank line and then after that shell prompt $, which means $a has \n which represents a new blank line.

This is as expected and perfect.

If there had been no \n is the $a, shell prompt $ would have appeared in the consecutive line and no blank line would have appeared.